# Sort array in Python (numpy) by two other lists

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have one array of vectors (or for simplicity you can assume I have one array) based on some computation I make 2 different arrays with same size of first array that contains number between 0 and 1 (for each index of the first array the second and third array containing the hamming distances) now I want to sort first array based on second and third array at the same time.
Since second and third array contains value between 0 and 1 I want to sort first array in order to each element has the closest distance of second and third array to the value 0.5.

If I want to make some realistic example :

```
first = numpy.array([1,2,3])    
second = numpy.array([0.2, 0.5, 0.97])   
third = numpy.array([0.3, 0.45, .98])

first = sort(first, second, third)
```

After that first must be something like this: `[2,1,3]` 
why I should have this?  because  second[1] and third[1] are the closest point to the (0.5,0.5)  (by closes I mean something like euclidean distance or any other one) and after index number 2 index number 0 has the second closes distance to point (0.5,0.5).

Or If I have `second = numpy.array([0.62, 0.61, 0.97])` and `third = numpy.array([0.49, 0.72, 0.97])` I want the sort array return indices like [0,1,2] so the first array after sorting is like this `[1,2,3]` why? because second[0] and third[0] are the closest point to the point (0.5,0.5) and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

first = np.array([1,2,3])
second = np.array([0.2, 0.5, 0.97])
third = np.array([0.3, 0.45, .98])

sqdist = (second-0.5)**2 + (third-0.5)**2
idx = np.argsort(sqdist)
first = first[idx]
print(first)
```

yields

```
[2 1 3]
```

Comment: I don't think this solution solve my problem because the second an third array has the same value for me,

Comment: Can you give another (longer?) example of `first`, `second`, `third` and the desired result?

Comment: for example if I have second = numpy.array([0.62, 0.61, 0.97]) and third = numpy.array([0.49, 0.72, 0.97]) your solution will return [1,0,2] but I want to return [0,1,2]

Comment: I don't know how to clear my question in order to make myself understood, you must assume the second and third array as a same value key I want to sort first array somehow that each equivalent index in second and third array has the minimum distances to the point (0.5, 0.5) something like! is it clear?

Comment: Then perhaps you are looking for `np.lexsort([np.abs(second-0.5), np.abs(third-0.5)])`. If that is not what you want, please show the calculation you are using to obtain `[0,1,2]`.

Comment: Okay, I've revised my answer.